# SQL query can't get desired output

Tags: sql, oracle, select

When I use this query,

```
select 
   receipt_num, trx_num, 
   (case when receipt_amount > 5000 then '1' else 'null') as stamp_value,receipt_amount 
from ra_customer_all where receipt_amount > 5000;
```

It gives output lik this:

```
receipt_num             trx_num           stamp_value     receipt_amount
   23679                sf35fd                 1              5400
   23679                sdf2424                1              5400 
   23679                rer434                 1              5400
  987444                dgd343                 1              98432
    7610                sdf23                  1              6756
    7610                dfg242                 1              6756
```

But I want output to look like this:

```
receipt_num        trx_num        stamp_value      receipt_amount
  23679            sf35fd             1                 5400
  23679            sdf2424            null              5400
  23679            rer434             null              5400
 987444            dgd343             1                 98432
   7610            sdf23              1                 6756
   7610            dfg242             null              6756
```

Where the stamp value should print only one time for each receipt num > 5000.

(*A single receipt may contain one or more trx_num*)

Please help me with this.

```
select 
acra.attribute6 office_code,
acra.attribute5 collection_number,
acra.receipt_number instrument_number,
 acra.receipt_date collection_date,
 acra.amount collected_amount,
ac.customer_name,
rcta.trx_number ,
(case  row_number() over (partition by acra.receipt_number order by rcta.trx_number)  when acra.amount > 5000 then '1'  else 'NULL' end) stamp_value,
from
ar_cash_receipts_all acra,
ar_customers ac,
ra_customer_trx_all rcta,
ar_receivable_applications_all araa
where
acra.pay_from_customer=ac.customer_id and
acra.cash_receipt_id = araa.cash_receipt_id and
araa.applied_customer_trx_id=rcta.customer_trx_id
and acra.amount > 5000
```

okay,i update my join query in which i added partition by but gives error as missing keyword.Can someone edit this for desired output

Comment: :please post the receipt_amount value also .

Comment: but all the values of  `receipt_amount` are greater that 5000. what else do u expect maybe u should try to have a value less than 5000 in the `receipt_amount` column.

Comment: sorry i forgot to add where condition.Now updated.

Comment: @sat33man : have you visit my link

Comment: @satindersingh Yes,But ur query is for the case when all receipt num are different.My question is different.I want stamp_value to be 1 for the first row in a group and NULL for all subsequent rows when receipt num is same.

Comment: Your modification to the partition by doesn't make sense. Please copy the partition by from my answer without changing it, run the query and check the output. You don't have to repeat the where clause in the partition by.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want stamp_value to be 1 for the first row in a group and NULL for all subsequent rows? Use PARTITION BY:

```
select 
   receipt_num, trx_num, 
   (case row_number() over (partition by receipt_num order by trx_num) 
     when 1 then 1
     else NULL
     end) stamp_value,
   receipt_amount
from ra_customer_all
where receipt_amount > 5000
```

This will set stamp_value to 1 for the first row (using trx_num for sorting) and NULL for all subsequent rows.

Comment: can u say how to use it join conditon like receipt_num X,trx_num Y.

Comment: Just add the where clause as usual (I updated my post). But this doesn't change the values for the data you've given, since all receipt_amount values are larger than 5000.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 select receipt_num,trx_num, result= 
case when receipt_amount >500 then 1 else null  end,receipt_amount from ra_customer_all
```

Demo
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f29a6/1

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f29a6/2

Answer (score 0):

Can you start by also including receipt_amount in your select statement for checking purposes? It could be that your expectation of receipt_amount is incorrect, and that the script behaves correctly.

Also, your null should not be in single quotes in the case statement, you will get a string in your resultset instead of a null value, as it seems you expect.

Comment: Nothing :you can post this in comments ,probably this is not the answer  thats why

Comment: I added amount.I think now my question is clear.can some one give me an idea.